# error: cannot import name 'pad' from 'skimage.util'

Tags: google-colaboratory

error pops up here
https://colab.research.google.com/github/AliaksandrSiarohin/first-order-model/blob/master/demo.ipynb?hl=ru#scrollTo=Oxi6-riLOgnm

I don’t understand programming at all, can I solve the error in the code here, or nothing depends on me?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you are going to attach a link to your code, please also attach your code to the question. Links can be blocked by web filters, and can go offline. Attaching your code to the question removes both these issues. I recommend you check out [ask] and [edit] your question to add formatted code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this issue on GitHub: https://github.com/AliaksandrSiarohin/first-order-model/issues/528

The problem is that "pad" is depreciated in the new versions of skimage, in other words, that function does not exist anymore in the new versions. You can overcome this error by editing the requirements file by running

`!pip install -U scikit-image==0.18.0`

There is a recent pull request to fix this issue so hopefully it will be merged soon. Run git pull in your terminal to get the updates. Hope this helps

Comment: for a while everything worked, but now when uploading a video (mp4) an error occurs https://ibb.co/qWpHKy5

Comment: @5opka Could you show me the code? There seems to be an issue with the URI that you're passing. Double-check that it's in the format you need to pass. I would suggest opening a new issue for this too if it persists.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/75918847/21357429