# error: `FFMPEG` can not read `<bytes>` in google colab

Tags: ffmpeg, google-colaboratory

the error occurs when loading a video file (mp4) previously the code worked with this video.
to run https://colab.research.google.com/github/AliaksandrSiarohin/first-order-model/blob/master/demo.ipynb
you need to put `!pip install -U scikit-image==0.18.0` in the first cell.
video can download this https://youtu.be/smQvWpqX13I (144p).
[image]

```
InitializationError         Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/imageio/core/imopen.py 
in imopen(uri, io_mode, plugin, extension, format_hint, 
legacy_mode, **kwargs)
    141         try:
--> 142             return loader(request, **kwargs)
    143         except InitializationError as class_specific:
    
20 frames
    
InitializationError: `FFMPEG` can not read `<bytes>`.

The above exception was the direct cause of the following 
exception:

RuntimeError           Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/imageio/core/imopen.py 
in imopen(uri, io_mode, plugin, extension, format_hint, 
legacy_mode, **kwargs)
    158 
    159         request.finish()
--> 160         raise err_type(err_msg) from err_from
    161 
    162     # fast-path based on format_hint

RuntimeError: `FFMPEG` can not handle the given uri.
```

Comment: solution - https://github.com/imageio/imageio/issues/968